prove the set $Z^{*}=\left\{ x\in X\mid\exists y\in\mathbb{R}:\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\left(x\in B_{n}\iff y\in V_{n}\right)\right\} $ is measurable
I am trying to prove that the following set $Z^{*}$ is measurable giving the following context:
Let $(X,S$) be a measure space, for any $Z\subset X$ we will define $S\!\upharpoonright\!Z=\left\{ Z\cap E\mid E\in S\right\}$.
Let $f:Z\to \mathbb R$ be $S\!\upharpoonright\!Z$ measurable. For $\langle V_n \mid n \in \mathbb N\rangle $ a basis for $\mathbb R$ we will define $\forall n\in \mathbb N$: $B_n$, a $S$ measurable set such that:
$$B_n \cap Z=f^{-1}(V_n).$$
Now let $Z^*=\left\{ x\in X\mid\exists y\in\mathbb{R}:\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\left(x\in B_{n}\iff y\in V_{n}\right)\right\}$, and prove that $Z^*$ is measurable.
I was able to prove:

that $\forall z\in Z$:
$\forall n \in \mathbb N: (z\in B_n \iff f(z)\in V_n)$

that $Z\subsetneq Z^*$


Now I am trying to prove that $Z^*$ is measurable I had few attempts but nothing worked, any help would be appreciated

"a basis for $\Bbb R$" - could you be more specific? A basis for the topology? A basis for the $\sigma$-algebra? A basis as a vector space is surely not it, since that would be only one element.

it was given as a  basis for the topology

I had made a mistake in my contemplation, so I deleted it. I can say that $x \in Z^$ if and only if the intersection of all $B_n$ containing $x$ also intersects $Z$ (in particular, $Z \subseteq Z^$).

I am aware that $Z\subset Z*$

To confirm, $Z$ is any subset of $X$ or does $Z$ have to be measurable ($Z \in S$)?

@user65023 any subset

Your proof that $Z\ne Z^*$ must be mistaken. It is quite easy to come up with examples where the two are the same. For example, when $Z = S$.

@PaulSinclair S is a subset of P(X) since it's a sigma algebra I don't understand how can Z=S, I guess that if X=Z then we get equality but I am not looking at the trivial case

Sorry, I meant $Z = X$. And that is only one example where $Z^* = Z$. There are many non-trivial cases.

@PaulSinclair I am not considering the trivial case of Z=X

For a non-trivial example, consider $X = \Bbb R \cup {p}$ where $p$ is a discrete point not in $\Bbb R$. Measurable sets are the measurable sets of $\Bbb R$ with and without $p$ added to them. $Z = \Bbb R$ and $f$ is the identity. The sets $B_n$ are taken as $V_n \cup {p}$. Since every $B_n$ contains $p$, but some $V_n$ do not intersect others, there can be no witness $y$ for $p$, so $p \notin Z^*$.

@PaulSinclair I see regardless is there a way I can prove that $Z^*$ is measruable?

If I had an answer, I would have given it. Unfortunately, my characterization of the elements of $Z^$ leads directly to a representation of it in terms of unions/intersections of uncountably many measurable sets, and I have not spotted a way to rectify that. I noticed the $Z^ = Z$ possibility while thinking about it and pointed it out to at least offer that correction.
